# How to colorize md-icon importing an svg icon?

Tags: html, css, svg, angular-material2

I would change the color of an icon.

I have imported **MdIconRegistry** and  **DomSanitizer**

```
import {MdIconRegistry} from '@angular/material';
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Than added the SVG to the registry

```
constructor ( mdIconRegistry: MdIconRegistry, sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {

     mdIconRegistry
       .addSvgIconInNamespace('img','linkedin',
           sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('../../assets/icons/linkedin.svg'));
  }
```

In .html file a call the icon

```
<md-icon svgIcon="img:linkedin" class="contacticon"  color="primary"></md-icon>
```

And modified the color and other parameters in CSS:

```
.contacticon{
    padding: 10%;
    fill:currentColor;
    color: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    font-size:200px;
}
```

Neither `color:primary` nor `fill: currentColor; color: red` are working.

How can I change the color ?

**Update** : this is the link of the [svg](https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/linkedin_174857#term=linkedin&page=1&position=2)

Comment: Is linkedin.svg a file you added yourself to your project? Are you able to modify it? It might be helpfull to post (or link) its source code

Comment: I get it from iconflat . I have updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the linkedin.svg file itself. Search for this: `style="fill:#0077B7;"` and exchange the color for `currentColor`. Then, setting `color` in your stylesheet will work.

(It is worth noting that the [licence](https://file000.flaticon.com/downloads/license/license.pdf) associated with the icon does allow its modification. Bat as it is a trademark, check LinkedIns policy about displaying their logo in different colors!)

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons why the CSS you wrote do not affect the icon.

1. There might be a more specific CSS rule affecting the icon. To debug this you will need to use something like Google Chrome devtools and inspect the element and check the computed tab. Make sure you check **show all** then type the property that you want to see from where does it inherit its value (like `color or`fill`). When you click the arrow it will display the applied value as well as reference to the CSS file you are using.

[image]

2. In Angular 2 when you are calling the SVG this way it might be injecting it as an `img` tag and this way you will not be able to change its color using `fill` or `color`.
3. If the SVG file itself has classes applied to its elements (like `path` ... etc) with specific style (like `fill` property) you will not be able to overwrite it using CSS `fill`. You need to remove these classes first.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this attribute to `md-icon` worked for me: `style="color:red;font:bold;"`.

Ex:

```
<md-icon style="color:red;font:bold;" >clear</md-icon>
```

Comment: The OP is asking for **SVG icons**, not **Material Icons by Google**.